# How to dismiss "edit home screen alert" in firebase Test Lab?

Tags: xctest, firebase-test-lab

When I start an XCTest on firebase, there is sometimes an alert asking to edit the home screen. Is it possible to disable it?

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Were you able to find a solution to this by any chance? I'm struggling with the same issue as well.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue, would really appreciate it if anyone had a solution. @user567 or Aditya Gurjar, have you found any solution?